# Get Webhook PHP and send by email

Tags: php, webhooks

I have created a PHP file that receives webhook notifications and writes them to a TXT file but I also want to receive them via email so I added the send email function but it doesn't work because there is a bug in testing. When I remove the lines "mail("my@email.eu","NEW MSG","$json");" it works without errors, so did I do something wrong? Please help.

```
<?php
$headers = "X-Event-Name: product.update";
$headers = "X-Event-Secret: my_key";
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
file_put_contents('log.txt', "$json", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
mail("my@email.eu","NEW MSG","$json");
http_response_code(204);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Considering the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for `mail()` it returns a boolean. Can you check if it returns `true` or `false` in your case? What do you mean by "it does not work"? Have you any output or error code?

Comment: The documentation also states: `It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.` so if it returns `true` it is being transported to the gateway but not necessarily delivered.

Comment: You also need some `SMTP` or other transport configuration in your `php.ini` to deliver mails.